# Custom Excel Function Data Type Issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

```
Function LogNormProb(Data As Range, Probability As Double) As Double

Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Data
    Cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Ln(Cell.Value)
Next Cell

LogNormProb = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Data)

End Function
```

I am trying to create a function to calculate the lognormal distribution of a dynamic range.  I am getting a #VALUE error with this as is and cannot figure out why.  Thank you for the help.

EDIT****

I apologize, here is where I am really trying to go.  I tried to update with your suggestion but I am still missing something.

```
Function LogNormProb(Data As Range, Probability As Double) As Double

Dim Cell As Range
Dim lnRange As Variant, lnAvg As Double
Dim lnStdDev As Double

For Each Cell In Data
    lnRange = WorksheetFunction.Ln(Cell.Value)
Next Cell

lnAvg = WorksheetFunction.Average(lnRange)
lnStdDev = WorksheetFunction.StdDev.S(lnRange)

LogNormProb = WorksheetFunction.LogNorm.INV(Probability, lnAvg, lnStdDev)

End Function
```

Comment: You cannot change other cells values in a function. You should store the lognormal results in a variable that you aggregate to. Output the final value.

Comment: Well first here on your edit you are trying to get the average and std dev of a single element array. I would think you need to instantiate lnRange as an array of the same dimensions as your range. You should add a break point early on your script and step through checking watches of each variable to see dimensions, data types, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UDF function can only change the values of the cell(s) it resides in - your udf is attempting to change the values of all the cells in Data.

try something like this (not tested)

```
Function LogNormProb(Data As Range, Probability As Double) As Double

Dim vData as variant
dim j as long
dim k as long

vData=Data.Value2

For j=lbound(vdata) to ubound(vdata)
for k= lbound(vdata,2) to ubound(vdata,2)
    vdata(j,k) = WorksheetFunction.Ln(vdata(j,k))
Next k
next j

LogNormProb = WorksheetFunction.Sum(vData)

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change other cells values in a function. You should store the lognormal results in a variable that you aggregate to, output the final value. Code would look like:

```
Function LogNormProb(Data As Range, Probability As Double) As Double

    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim dbTotal As Double

    For Each Cell In Data
        dbTotal = dbTotal + WorksheetFunction.Ln(Cell.Value)
    Next Cell

    LogNormProb = dbTotal

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you I am apparently still missing something, see my edit please.